# Is the app will be approved by apple if the user registration is only through website not through app and can access the login content in the app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Is the app will be  approved by apple if the user registration is only through website not through app and can access the login content in the app. 
In the website it might use some payment if needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Short answer, yes, it's valid.  However, your app should make NO reference to the sign up process or link to it in anyway and should make NO reference to payments or any other mention of paid services, otherwise Apple will require a 30% cut.  See Netflix for an example. (I will however admit that my understanding of the requirements may not be correct as there is little "direct" information on the subject, allowing Apple to change it's mind and not be in violation of it's own rules ... like that would stop it )

Comment: Is that means I've to make sure there shouldn't be any registration button or link in the app. I've to allow only login .

Comment: That's right, any mention of purchases or links to site/services which require payment falls under Apple's "Apple Pay" umbrella - so unless you want to pay apple 30%, you can't make any mention of it

Comment: That's the answer what I needed thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will approve. Make sure to follow these steps:

1. Leave no traces about your website or payment in your app.
2. Provide a demo username/password to Apple so that they can login and go through your app at the time of review process.

Good luck!